# Azure VM - Slow to load website. Any Tips?

Tags: performance, azure

[image: VM Usage Snapshot]Im currently testing a website on a VM in Microsoft Azure, however the site is much slower since moving from a private hosting company.
I have taken a snapshot of the reporting near a peak of its daily traffic. 
Do you think it needs more than 2 cores?
Are there any practical tips to speeding up a website on a VM?
Also does anyone feel that a cloud service is better/quicker than a VM? (Im assuming its virtually the same thing...)
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart shows CPU utilization peaked at 0.44%. It is barely using the CPUs it has, so adding more won't help.  All of the metrics in your chart are very low -- the server appears to have much more capacity than you need.

This implies the slowdown is not a hardware resource problem. I would start by looking for a software or configuration problem, a network problem or a problem with the measurement technique.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea idea for how to measure latency from a user to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here: i installed wamp, uniform server, xamp and the website i was testing is around 20 times slower than in my web server. It takes around 1.5seconds to start recieving a response from apache.